# C2094: unknown label 'sil' -- why can't I access the sil register on VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

Using Visual Studio 2013, I'm trying to get this to compile, but I'm getting C2094:

```
int main(){
    __asm{
        mov esi, 0x12345678;
        movzx esi, sil;
    }
    return 0;
} // this is line 7
```

However, I'm getting:

```
test.cpp(7) : error C2094: label 'sil' was undefined
```

`sil` is not a label, but an 8-bit register that's just the lowest part of `esi`. Why can't I access it?

I'm using [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Table_of_x86_Registers_svg.svg) registers table as a reference.

Comment: Write your code in C, run it, stop with a debugger, right click, view the dis-assembly and find out exactly how it can be written in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [no inline assembly support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk4z78b(v=vs.120).aspx) for x64 in the MSVC compilers. So you are likely compiling for 32 bit, but there's no `sil` register in [x86](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561502(v=vs.85).aspx)